# To read excel grouped rows/column data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to read grouped of  rows/column data in excel  and display on the another sheet using VBA.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguous, but if what you want is to copy the visible grouped data to another sheet, something like the code below will help you do that:

```
Sub foo()
    Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```